# Ngif with images Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

I have 5 'pages' like

```
http://localhost:4201/app?part=1
http://localhost:4201/app?part=2
http://localhost:4201/app?part=3
....
```

And I have 5 images, and I would like to match each image to each page with help of `ngIf` (if it is possible).

For this purpose in my Component I have this line, which tells me which part do I have now

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.pageNumber = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams["part"];
}
```

Also I have in my Component

```
myImg = '../../assets/image1.jpg';
```

And in template I have

```
<img [src]="myImg"/>
```

What I want to have is like logic like

```
if pageNumber = 1 then <img [src]="myImg1"/>
if pageNumber = 2 then <img [src]="myImg2"/>
if pageNumber = 3 then <img [src]="myImg3"/>
```

and so on...

Could you please tell me how could I write ngIf statement in my case? I tried examples from documentation, but none of them worked for me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a condition. Instead, put only one picture, and set its source like this

```
<img [src]="myPathToImage + imageNumber + imageExt" />
```

In your controller

```
myPathToImage = "../../assets/image";
imageNumber = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams["part"];
imageExt = ".jpg";
```

By the way, if you are using angular CLI and didn't touche the folder structure, I think that your path is `assets/...` and not `../../assets/...`

Answer (score 2):

It's good practice to manipulate data inside the Component class and not on the Template

In your component's class you could do:

```
ngOnInit(){
    let pageNumber = this.pageNumber = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams["part"];
    this.imageToBeDisplayedOnTemplate = `myImg${pageNumber}.jpg`
}
```

Then on your template:

```
<img [src]="imageToBeDisplayedOnTemplate"/>
```